# Unwrap doesn't work properly

Tags: uv

I've been working on a model and I want to unwrap it in order to apply textures.

Problem is, when I click on "unwrap", the model doesn't take all the space available, and some parts are stretched in a very weird way, even tho (I believe) the unwrap was done correctly, and anyway I think it'd be impossible for it to look like that, even if I made a mistake.

The scale is 1 1 1 (I've applied both rotation and scale).
Furthermore, when I click on "unwrap" once again, nothing changes, it looks like it is stuck, somehow.

Any ideas?
Thanks.
[image]

this is the stretched part of the model. As you can see,it's basically a cylinder, and you can notice my seams.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red outlines on your vertices in the UV editor show that you've pinned those vertices. Pinning prevents Unwrap from moving them again, which is useful in allowing you to retain any parts you are happy with. Pin by pressing 'P' and unpin with 'Alt-P' (within the UV Editor).

To address the UVs not taking up enough space: you can manually grab/rotate/scale in the UV editor to directly fix this. Selecting vertices and pressing 'L' will select all linked parts of the mesh by UV seam/island.
So - again, in UV editor - if you select a vertex in the tall part of your mesh, hit 'L' to get all linked, 'alt-P' to unpin it, then in the 3D view do 'u > Unwrap' once again, you should see a revised unwrap of the problematic part.

And as Per's answer above -- other automatic unwrapping types are also available, such as projection from view -- but knowing how to manually re-unwrap subparts of your mesh is always useful.

Comment: thanks for your help, I must have accidentally press the P button.

Comment: @Raio Boss don't post thank you comments, upvote the post instead. If it completely solved your problem consider marking it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into orthogonal view
2. Go to the front view
3. Select the front faces
4. Go to UV and choose project from view
5. Rinse and repeat for the back and if necessary sides.
6. Remember you can select the individual UVs and move and scale them on the uv map.